# Trigger an Azure Function upon VM creation

Tags: python, azure, function, triggers, serverless

I'm looking for a way to trigger an Azure Function which will run some Python code, each time a new virtual machine is created. I have already done the same thing in AWS using CloudWatch + Lambda, but I can't find where/how achieve the same thing in Azure.

I have tried to use Logic App with Event Grid but there is no trigger to monitor VM state.

Anyone could provide me with some guidance here ?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://edi.wang/post/2020/6/18/use-azure-function-to-schedule-auto-start-for-vms

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's the other way around I'm trying to achieve. Meaning that it's the vm creation which is the trigger.

Comment: I think this trigger operation is not supported by azure function now.

Comment: Hi, that's what I assumed unfortunately.

Comment: I think even if azure don't have built-in method to do this, but you can design a custom way to check the add operation of VM. You can have a look of my answer.

Comment: You can use the code provided by me to check whether the VM has a creation operation. It is based on the REST API of the Azure Management Service. After running, you can check all the VM instances in your subscription. You can poll to determine whether there is an increase operation. And if you need it, here is the official REST API reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list#resourceidentitytype

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: Hi, not yet I have put that aside for the moment, but planning to go back to that beginning of March ;-). I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Azure service don't have built-in method to achieve your requirement, but I think you can achieve this by your own python code. The main logic is to polling the VM names from your subscription and then store the VM names in somewhere, if they changes, post a request to something like 'HttpTrigger' endpoint(Or just put the logic in the polling algorithm.).

And the for the polling algorithm, you can design by yourself or just use the 'TimeTrigger' to achieve.

I notice you add the 'Python' tag, so just use code like below and put them inside a polling algorithm:

```
import requests
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential 
import json

client_id = 'xxx'
tenant_id = 'xxx'
client_secret = 'xxx'
subscription_id = 'xxx'

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

accesstoken = str(credential.get_token('https://management.azure.com/.default'))[19:1287]
bearertoken = "Bearer "+accesstoken

r = requests.get("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"+subscription_id+"/resources?$filter=resourceType eq 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'&api-version=2020-06-01",headers={'Authorization': bearertoken})
items = json.loads(r.text)
print(r.text)
for item in items['value']:
    print(item['name'])#This line is print, you need to store this in some place such as database, azure blob storage, azure table storage etc.

#check the VM names here. If some VM been added, post a request to the HttpTrigger function.
```

If you use azure function 'Time Trigger' instead of self-designed algorithm, then you can store the client id, tenent id, client_secret and subscription id to the keyvault and then let your function app configuration settings refer to the keyvault, this will make it safe.

Above code is based on AAD bearer token, you need to create a AAD App and let it have the 'Owner' RBAC role of the subscription. You need to something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This just like a 'custom trigger' that trigger by the VM created in your 'subscription'. And I think your VM will not be many, so it will not consume much computing resources.

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable input ! I have assumed that I had to make some kind of polling against the Azure API and use Python sets for instance. I'll let you know how that goes.